# Кастомизированный список на Java

Tags: java, swing, list

Подскажите, как кастомизировать список, созданный на Java? (`java.awt.List`)
А именно нужно добавить разделители между элементами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вам придется переопределять Render для списка.

Вот есть [готовый пример](http://esus.com/creating-a-jcombobox-with-a-divider-separator-line/) с разделителителями с `JComboBox`:

```
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
   public Test() {
      getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      final JComboBox combobox =
         new JComboBox(new Object[] {
               "Item 1",
               new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL),
               "Item 2",
               new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL),
               "Item 3",
               new JSeparator(JSeparator.HORIZONTAL),
               "Item 4",
               "Item 5"
            }
         );

      getContentPane().add(combobox);
      combobox.setRenderer(new SeparatorComboBoxRenderer());
      combobox.addActionListener(new SeparatorComboBoxListener(combobox));

      addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(1);
         }
      });     

      setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Test main = new Test();
      main.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class SeparatorComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer implements ListCellRenderer
{
   public SeparatorComboBoxRenderer() {
      super();
   }

   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList list,
           Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      if (isSelected) {
          setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
          setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
      }
      else {
          setBackground(list.getBackground());
          setForeground(list.getForeground());
      }

      setFont(list.getFont());
      if (value instanceof Icon) {
         setIcon((Icon)value);
      }
      if (value instanceof JSeparator) {
         return (Component) value;
      }
      else {
         setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
      }

      return this;
  } 
}

class SeparatorComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {
   JComboBox combobox;
   Object oldItem;

   SeparatorComboBoxListener(JComboBox combobox) {
      this.combobox = combobox;
      combobox.setSelectedIndex(0);
      oldItem = combobox.getSelectedItem();
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object selectedItem = combobox.getSelectedItem();
      if (selectedItem instanceof JSeparator) {
         combobox.setSelectedItem(oldItem);
      } else {
         oldItem = selectedItem;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать свой класс JList и ему задать Renderer. Необходимо  имплиментить интерфейс  ListCellRenderer для класса представляющего редера!

Возможно вам поможет [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786907/java-list-with-line-separation), пример конкретно для JList!